# Layout reloads for subpage

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Sveltekit reloads the layout (Sidebar part) of the page, even though the route is part of a subpage.

I have the following routes:

```
+layout.svelte <- contains Sidebar
/[item]
 +page.server.ts
 +page.svelte
/new-item
 +page.server.ts
 +page.svelte
```

- Navigating to any of the /[item] routes only loads the page content, while the sidebar is not reloaded.
- Navigating to /new-item route however triggers a reload of the layout/sidebar part as well with a white page flash.

During debugging, I came to realize that it probably is due to the sidebar containing links to items with /[item], but no link to /new-item.

One could assume, even though it might a route is not directly linked, sveltekit should be smart enough to understand that it doesn't need to reload the layout of a subpage, or is there a config somewhere that I couldn't find yet?

(Unfortunately, I have no minimal code repo to share)

Comment: Reloads can also happen if you have redirects in code that do not use `goto`.

Comment: What navigation method are you using?

Comment: Standard rendering (SSR) and navigation on sidebar is via a links, server-side via sveltekit's redirect.

Comment: Why goto? @H.B. Sveltekit's method is redirect.

Comment: `redirect` is something to set a HTTP header on the server, `goto` is for redirects on the client.

Comment: Ah, yes correct. I noticed now that the layout/sidebar reload only happens when redirect is used server-side.